# Write scheme LISP Atomic_Count

Tags: racket

can someone help me to solve this problem?

- (define test1 '(c o 2 (h 2 o) 3 o 2))
- (define test2 '(h 2 o))
- (define    test3 '(c o 2 o 2))
- (atomic_count test1) returns 14
- (atomic_count test2) returns 3
- (atomic_count test3) returns 5

Comment: Please, could you be more specific?

Comment: Why is it the case that "(atomic_count test1) returns 14"?  If you're trying to count atoms, I'd have expected 9.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor 14 is correct: 1 + 1*2 + (1 * 2 + 1) * 3 + 1 * 2.

Comment: LOL.. Atoms in LISP are things that are not lists. It seems you are using the word atom as elements of molecules (like chemistry and not computer programming). You need to specify these things. Also if you want code in answer you must supply what you have done so far.

Comment: @uselpa Ah, so it's supposed to be "add 1 for a symbol followed by a non number" and "add the number for a symbol followed by a number."

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I seem to be the only one remembering chemistry... must be because I hated it so much. You can break it down to "1 for a symbol, (previous * number) for a number". Don't forget sublists, they don't fit into your description. While the question is certainly close-worthy, I found the problem entertaining ;-)

Comment: @uselpa I remember the chemistry OK, it's just that "atoms" is a technical term in lisps, so a question about counting atoms, unless otherwise qualified, would seem to be about that.  Plus, in the other two examples, the lisp-atom interpretation works:  the list `'(h 2 o)` contains three atoms: `h`, `2`, and `o`, and `'(c o 2 o 2)` has five.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not too hard, the main point is that you need some kind of buffer (called `prev` in my case) to wait for a possible multiplication:

```scm
(define (atomic_count lst)
  (let loop ((lst lst) (prev 0))
    (if (null? lst) 
        prev
        (let ((elt (car lst)))
          (cond
            ((list? elt)   (+ prev (loop (cdr lst) (loop elt 0))))
            ((number? elt) (loop (cdr lst) (* prev elt)))
            (else          (+ prev (loop (cdr lst) 1))))))))
```

Testing:

```scm
> (atomic_count '(c o 2 (h 2 o) 3 o 2))
14
> (atomic_count '(h 2 o))
3
> (atomic_count '(c o 2 o 2))
5
```

Comment: You were lucky that I was faster than the close-voters. Next time try to show some effort please.

Comment: okay, i'm sorry because i'm new in scheme lisp